# Django - "Find latest" of children for all rows

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I'm having difficulties with 'aggregate' and 'latest' .

I've got these two models :

```
class Word(models.Model):
    ESSENTIALWORDS = 'EW'
    FOOB = 'ER'
    OTHER = 'OT'
    WORDSOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (ESSENTIALWORDS, 'Essential Words'),
        (FOOB, 'FOOB'),
        (OTHER, 'OTHER'),
    )

    level = models.IntegerField()
    word = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                              choices=WORDSOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES,
                              default=OTHER)
    hint = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)


class Attempt(models.Model):
    learner = models.ForeignKey(Learner)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to find all `Word` objects for which the most recent `Attempt` (based on the Field `when`) has a `success` value of True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

Word.objects.annotate(latest=Max('attempt__when'))
            .filter(attempt__success=True,
                    attempt__when=F('latest'))
```

First, every `Word` is [annotated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) with the date of the most recent (i.e. the [`Max`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max)) attempt. Then the `Word` objects are filtered to only include ones that have a matching `Attempt` where `success` is `True` and where the date matches the latest date. ([`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) is used to represent the value of another column—or in this case, an annotation.)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'm sorry I took so long to acknowledge but it actually took me a little while to work out whether the answer produced was indeed the right one ! My next task is to understand better *why* it works ;-). Thanks again.

Comment: @glaucon: You're welcome. I added an explanation to hopefully make it more clear. If you follow the links and read about annotation and F objects, I think it will make sense.